# Panel expand on button click and overflow on top of image

Tags: html, css

I am still a beginner at this but, I have created a login page with validation. Which works fine but when I test for validation with nothing in the textbox and click login button the panel expands and overflows on top of image. What I am looking for is there something I can do to fix this.

[LoginImagebefore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FttDQ.jpg)
[LoginImageafter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoVws.jpg)

```
<div class="proofTrackSend">
<img src="../Images/Proof-Track-Send.png" width="335" height="350" />
        </div>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="loginImage ">
            <img src="../Images/Login_Logo.png" height="130" width="300" />
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: 10%; width: 350px;">
            <dx:ASPxRoundPanel ID="ASPxRoundPanel1" runat="server"
                HeaderText="User Login"
                DefaultButton="btnLogin"
                Theme="iOS"
                Width="350px" View="GroupBox" BackColor="#E1ECF5" ForeColor="#1C6E88">
                <PanelCollection>

                    <dx:PanelContent>
                        <div style="position: relative;">
                            <div>
                                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbUserName" runat="server"
                                    Width="295px"
                                    Theme="iOS"
                                    Caption="User Name">
                                    <ClientSideEvents Init="function(s,e){s.Focus();}" />
                                    <CaptionSettings Position="bottom" />
                                    <ValidationSettings ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" ErrorTextPosition="Right" Display="Dynamic" ErrorDisplayMode="Text">
                                        <RequiredField ErrorText="User Name is required." IsRequired="true" />
                                    </ValidationSettings>
                                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbPassword" runat="server"
                                    Password="true"
                                    Width="295px"
                                    Theme="iOS"
                                    Caption="Password">
                                    <CaptionSettings Position="bottom" />
                                    <ValidationSettings ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" ErrorTextPosition="Right" Display="Dynamic" ErrorDisplayMode="Text">
                                        <RequiredField ErrorText="Password is required." IsRequired="true" />
                                    </ValidationSettings>
                                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <div>
                                <div style="float: left">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="LOGIN" CssClass="button"
                                        OnClick="btnLogin_Click" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" ForeColor="White" />
                                </div>
                                <div style="float: right">
                                    <dx:ASPxHyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Account/ForgotPassword.aspx" Text="Forgot your password?" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                    </dx:PanelContent>

                </PanelCollection>
                <Border BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="5px" />
            </dx:ASPxRoundPanel>
        </div>
        <br />
```

CSS:

```
html {
    background-color: white
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 1300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.truckImage {
    width: 873px;
    height: 210px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.loginImage {
    width: 300px;
    height: 130px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}

.button {
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 145px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: left center;
    padding-left: 5px;
    background-color: #82B5D2;
    border-color: #1A94BB;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}

.proofTrackSend {
    width: 335px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 54%;
    margin-top: 120px;
}


 I am lost on how to move image over when the panel expands
```

Comment: just put your error message under every input field (it's an example)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and it works!